# HTML multiple pages on same file

Tags: html

i managed to do 2 pages on same file but when i try 3 with this same technique it doesn't work.

```
<script>
    function show(shown, hidden, hidden) {
      document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
      document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
      document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="show('Page2','Page1','Page3');" class="bminappi">BMI-laskuri</a>
```

Now this button shows content of Page 1 and 2 on same page but not the 3rd. I would like it to show only Page 2.

The pages are divs like this: (except page1 doest have display:none)

```
<div id="Page2" style="display:none">
```

Comment: You can't have 2 parameters with the same name `show(shown, hidden, hidden)` and have it work the way you expect. Maybe you need some sort of array or list.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just created a site like this yesterday, and I've created many in the past (the most simple of them being this one: http://oops-studio.com/twinsremasteredobstaclecreator/helppage/)

How I usually do it is to just make every page a div which is a massive container for everything on the page, and then give it a class like `page` or something.

Then you can create a function like `changePageTo(index)` and have that loop through every page and set its `style.display = "none";` then taking the target page and `style.display = "block";`

An example would be like so:

```
let pages = document.getElementsByClassName("page");

function changePageTo(index){
    for(let i = 0;i < pages.length;i++){
        pages[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    pages[index].style.display = "block";
}
```

You could also display pages using assigned names if you'd like, rather than indexes. How I would usually do that is just like so:

```
let pages = document.getElementsByClassName("page");
let pageNames = ["Cookies","Another page","The last page"];// One name per page element

function changePageTo(name){
    let index = pageNames.indexOf(name);
    if(index === -1){// If the page doesn't exist
        // Do whatever you want in here
        return;
    }
    for(let i = 0;i < pages.length;i++){
        pages[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    pages[index].style.display = "block";
}
```

Hope this answers your question!

---

Here's a working example:

```js
let pages = document.getElementsByClassName("page");

function changePageTo(index){
    for(let i = 0;i < pages.length;i++){
        pages[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    pages[index].style.display = "block";
}

changePageTo(0);
```

```html
<div class = "page">
  <h1>This is page one. It's titled "Cookies"</h1>
</div>
<div class = "page">
  <h1>This is page two. It's titled "Another page"</h1>
</div>
<div class = "page">
  <h1>This is page three. It's titled "The last page"</h1>
</div>
<button onclick = "changePageTo(0)">Show page 1</button>
<button onclick = "changePageTo(1)">Show page 2</button>
<button onclick = "changePageTo(2)">Show page 3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have two parameters with the same name in your function which means when you refer to them it will only use the first instance of it.

If you change the names slightly, like I have below, I think you should be sorted.

```
function show(shown, hidden1, hidden2) {
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(hidden1).style.display='none';
  document.getElementById(hidden2).style.display='none';
}
```